# Strange error defining a macro with arguments for math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

When I delete the second `\item`, it compiles fine. However, with the second `\item`, I get `ERROR: Missing $ inserted` and the math renders incorrectly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand \frob[2] {\langle #1,#2 \rangle_F}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item What I want: $ 
\langle A,B \rangle_F 
\geq 
\langle C,D \rangle_F
$. 

\item What I get: $ 
\frob{A,B} 
\geq 
\frob{A,B} 
$.

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: the issue]

Would appreciate any help with this issue!

Comment: Don't use `\frob` as `\frob{A,B} ` but use it as `\frob{A}{B}`. Your `\frob`-macro does process two arguments which are **not** comma-separated. As result it delivers something where the phrases delivered via the arguments will be comma-separated. Maybe this confused you. ;-) If you do `\frob{A,B}\geq`, `\frob`'s first undelimited argument will be formed from `{A,B}` and `\frob`'s second undelimited argument will be formed from `\geq`. So all in all `\frob{A,B} \geq \frob{A,B} ` should be `\frob{A}{B}\geq\frob{C}{D} `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `\frob` to take *two* arguments

```
\newcommand{\frob}[2]
```

However, you're only passing it *one* argument when you use it like this

```
\frob{A,B}
```

That's because arguments are specified as *tokens* or using *braces* `{`...`}`, not a comma-separated list of elements.

Since you're printing the same thing as you're passing, the following might be simpler:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\frob}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle_F}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item
    What I want: $ 
    \langle A,B \rangle_F 
    \geq 
    \langle C,D \rangle_F
    $. 

  \item 
    What I get: $ 
    \frob{A,B} 
    \geq 
    \frob{A,B} 
    $.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you really want to pass two arguments, then your definition should be

```
\newcommand{\frob}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle_F}
```

and you'll use it via `\frob{A}{B}`.

Comment: Ah, obviously! I've used `\frac` that way, but somehow had a brain fart when defining my own function. Thanks!